# Why do I get the error: "double free or corruption(out) core dumped Aborted core dumped", when trying to free memory on heap?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, valgrind

I have used a malloc 2-D array and this it:

```
charArray = (char **)malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    charArray[i] = (char *)malloc(columns * sizeof(char *));
```

And when I try to free the memory, it says: "double free or corruption(out). Aborted (core dumped). This is how i free it:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    free(charArray[i]);
    charArray[i] = NULL;
}

free(charArray);
charArray = NULL;
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it? This is the valgrind report:

[image]

Comment: we need to see more.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] so we can see the full behaviour of your program from beginning to end?

Comment: One thing that is interesting in the code you have shown is the allocation using `columns` `for(i=0;i<columns;i++)`and the deallocation using `rows` `for(i=0;i<rows;i++)`. Seems like those should match up. Since you also have an out of bounds access I'm going to guess that's it.

Comment: Yes, found it mate, thank you!!

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted it is hard too see.

Make your life easier and use array pointers.

```
char (*charArray)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*charArray));
```

Only one allocation and free is needed. Fewer levels of indirection - faster code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment is terse to say the least, but there is a problem in the allocation loop: `for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)` should iterate on `rows`, not `columns` and allocate `columns` characters, not pointers.

If `rows` and `columns` differ, you have undefined behavior:

- either `columns > rows` and the allocation code writes pointers beyond the end of the allocated block for `charArray`
- or `rows > columns` and you attempt to free pointers that were not allocated and are probably invalid.

To avoid such mistakes, it is recommended to use `sizeof` with type of the destination element:

```
    char **charArray = calloc(rows, sizeof(*charArray));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        charArray[i] = calloc(columns, sizeof(*charArray[i]));
```

It would also be simpler to allocate a flat 2D array of `char` instead of an indirect array:

```
    char (*charArray)[columns] = calloc(rows, sizeof(*charArray));
```

This array is also simpler to free:

```
    free(charArray);
```